# How they work: dehumidifier vs air conditioner

Tags: thermodynamics, humidity

From what I understand both dehumidifiers and air conditioners do the same thing. They blow air onto cooled pipes. This means that dehumidifiers must cool the air and air conditioners must dehumidify as well. So what is the difference in operation between them? How do their internal mechanisms differ?

Comment: This is probably better suited for Engineering SE IMO

Answer (score 0):

the mass flow rate of air through a dehumidifier is typically low, to furnish the longest time possible for heat transfer from the cold coils to the air. This means that the compressor rating of a dehumidifier is also low, meaning that its capacity as a refrigeration device will be relatively low.

the mass flow rate of air through a room air conditioner is typically high, to furnish the largest possible flow of cooled air into the room. This means that the compressor rating of a room air conditioner is also high, meaning that its capacity as a refrigeration device will be relatively high as well.